# Browser sends cookie with "SameSite=Strict" attribute on another domain

Tags: web-browser, cookies, csrf, same-site-cookies

I am solving PortSwigger's lab: "CSRF where token is tied to non-session cookie". For testing SameSite attribute I created a cookie in my browser with `SameSite=Strict` for domain `https://<id>.web-security-academy.net/`.

[image]

Then on `https://exploit-<id>.web-security-academy.net/exploit` I hosted the exploit with the payload:

```
<form method="post" action="https://<id>.web-security-academy.net/my-account/change-email">
   <input type="hidden" name="email" value="hello@email.ru">
</form>

<img src="foo" onerror="document.forms[0].submit()">
```

I expected that my browser won't send my cookie with `SameSite=Strict` when I open exploit, but it adds them.

[image]

Can you explain why, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: because `samesite` doesn't mean "same *origin*"<s>, webapps were a mistake</s>, and cookie security <s>is a disaster</s>considers most subdomains equivalent *for the specific purpose of the `samesite` flag*.

---

Cookies have a peculiar and unique approach to domains. Without going into the full details here, the "site" for a cookie is substantially broader in scope than the origin of a site (which is well-defined and generally excludes the things you might expect). Pages across different ports of the same domain are considered same-site, and until recently the same was true of pages across different schemes (protocols) such that http://example.com/ could cause samesite cookies - including secure cookies unavailable to the request origin - to be sent for https://example.com/.

The real mess, though, is in subdomains (as you found). If you want to go to the canonical source, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-same-site-00, in particular section 2.1, and try to figure out what the heck it means (I'll save you the effort, for the part needed to answer your question, below).

There is a concept of a "site for cookies" (see 2.1.1 of the RFC), which is "either a registrable domain, or the empty string". OK, so what's a "registrable domain"? Goooood question. [Is the "same registrable domain" a sound security basis for cookies?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/222705/is-the-same-registrable-domain-a-sound-security-basis-for-cookies) tries to get an answer to that, but the very short version is: usually it's the root zone + the top-level domain (also known as "TLD+1"). So, "registrabledoma.in" is *probably* a registrable domain (in India's TLD), but "unregistrable.domain.com" is *probably* not; the relevant registrable domain would be "domain.com".

I stress *probably* because it's not as simple as "no subdomains". There's a thing called the [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), maintained by Mozilla and used by all major browsers, that documents under what suffixes people are allowed to register names. Looking at the list, we can see that "com" is a public suffix (have fun searching for it; I recommend a regular expression), so "domain.com" is a registrable domain. "domain.com" is **not** a public suffix, so "unregistrable.domain.com" is not a registrable domain. (Some other examples of public suffixes include "co.uk", "fr.eu.org", "environmentalconservation.museum", and "s3.dualstack.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com".)

---

Anyhow, bringing this back to your question:

"web-security-academy.net" is not a public suffix, but "net" is. As such, the registrable domain is "web-security-academy.net" for both "<id>.web-security-academy.net" and for "exploit-<id>.web-security-academy.net". Since they are also both HTTPS, they are - for cookie purposes - **the same site**. There's your answer.

This **doesn't** mean they're the same *domain* for cookie purposes <s>(that would be consistent, you see)</s>, so requests to the one domain don't get cookies scoped exclusively to the other domain. Though it will get cookies scoped to a common parent, unless the domain scope is unspecified and thus implicitly "the current domain *without subdomains*, a property that can't be specified explicitly. Also you aren't allowed to scope cookies to a public suffix, which is very reasonable once a list of such things exists at all.

Anyhow, now you know why `samesite` is not considered a fully adequate mitigation for CSRF, even on conforming browsers. It's because what they conform to is <s>insane</s>less restricting than you expect.